# simulation problem due to the library import

Tags: python-2.7

I found a problem in the python program.I don't know what I have to do.
Cordially.

```
import pyautogui
im1 = pyautogui.screenshot()
im2 = pyautogui.screenshot('my_screenshot.png')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/yyyu.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    import pyscreeze
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator (__init__.py, line 168)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably get this error because you use python 2, try to use python 3

Comment: pyautogui should work for both python2 and python3.